# C# PostMessage - How to prevent data loss?

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, postmessage

I have an application that will form a packet and send the packet data to an external program to send. I have everything working, but my only method I know that doesn't require the window to be the foremost is PostMessage. However, it seems to always lose 0-2 characters at the beginning of the message. Is there a way I can make a check to prevent the loss? I've tried looping GetLastError() and re-sending it if it's 0, but it doesn't help any. Here's the code I've gotten so far:

```
    public void SendPacket(string packet)
    {
        //Get window name
        IntPtr hWnd = Window.FindWindow(null, "???????????");
        //Get the first edit box handle
        IntPtr edithWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TEdit", "");
        //Get the handle for the send button
        IntPtr buttonhWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TButton", "SEND");
        //Iterate twice to get the edit box I need
        edithWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(hWnd, edithWnd, "TEdit", "");
        edithWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(hWnd, edithWnd, "TEdit", "");
        foreach (Char c in packet)
        {
            SendCheck(c, edithWnd);
        }
        //Press button
        TextSend.PostMessageA(buttonhWnd, 0x00F5, 0, 0);
        //Clear the edit box
        TextSend.SendMessage(edithWnd, 0x000C, IntPtr.Zero, "");
    }

    public void SendCheck(char c, IntPtr handle)
    {
        //Send the character
        TextSend.PostMessageA(handle, 0x102, c, 1);
        //If error code is 0 (failure), resend that character
        if (TextSend.GetLastError() == 0)
            SendCheck(c, handle);
        return;
    }
```

And here are the definitions in TextSend class:

```
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetLastError();
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, string s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're finding a TEdit and a TButton makes me think that the target application was written in Delphi.  If so, depending on the version of Delphi it may or may not be a Unicode application.  You're calling PostMessageA instead of PostMessageW which means it's sending a single-byte Ansi char instead of a 16-bit Unicode char from the c# application.

Do you have source to the target application? Stuffing data in an edit box and clicking a button seems a bit fragile.  If you can modify the target application there are certainly other options available than to send one character at a time.

Comment: You are right, it is written if Delphi. I have the source as well, but I do not have a Delphi compiler. I had it before my hard drive failed, but I cannot find the Borland Delphi 7 download I had installed. 

As for the application, I don't think the problem lies with Unicode characters. Otherwise I'd lose more than just the first few characters, at least I think that's right.

For editing the target application, what did you have in mind? I've never coded in Delphi and the application is not made by me.

Comment: Ok, so D7 is definitely not Unicode.  If you could modify the Delphi app there are all kinds of interprocess communication capabilities such as using a memory-mapped file.  You could also send the entire string at once using wm_copydata instead of WM_CHAR (your 0x102 constant).  How big is the Delphi app?

Comment: The application is pretty small. Basically it has a main window that monitors packets being sent and received and a second window that can send a packet after you give it the data. The second window is the one I need the data sent to. I have tried using the WM_COPYDATA constant, but I never got it to work at all. I'm pretty sure my use was wrong. It was basically `SendMessage(TEditHandle, WM_COPYDATA, TEditParentHandle, ref CopyDataStructure);`

Comment: WM_COPYDATA wouldn't work at all unless there's explicit code in the Delphi app that knows how to handle that particular message. WM_CHAR is working simply because the target edit control that you're sending to knows what to do with it.  If you're always just losing the first few characters it may be a timing thing.  You might add a really big delay (like 1 second) between each char sent in order to possibly _see_ what's going on in the other application.

Comment: There is the following code in the main window of the Delphi application: `procedure TFormAlissaA.WMCopyData(var msg: TWMCopyData);` However if I move to the main window to send (Which I can in a certain situation I think), I cannot get the edit handle. The TEdit in the main form that send/receives packets is in a TPanel along with a button. I can get the button handle fine, but for some reason I cannot get that specific edit handle. I try getting it directly like I did above and try to get it through the TPanel child handles, which works perfectly for the button but not the TEdit.

Comment: If the main form already has a WM_COPYDATA handler then it's probably being used for some other purpose and trying to send the data there is likely to break something. As far as finding the other TEdit there may be another panel in the hierarchy or something else causing the problem.  If I could see the Delphi code I'd be able to help more but I'm not sure that these back and forth comments are the best approach.  I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I'll just make another post to ask about this. Basically, the structure is TPanel - (TEdit | TButton) TPanel2 - (5 TButton's). However, getting either panel handle works, button handle only works on one, and edit handle works on neither. It's strange to me. Anyway, thanks for the help.